# Cheap/simple way to turn TV on/off using computer and/or Windows Meda Center remote

Tags: windows-media-center, power, htpc, remote-control

I have a Windows Media Center HTPC, and it's great.  I'm trying to rid myself of one last minor inconvenience, though.  The only thing I need my TV remote for on a day-to-day basis is to turn the TV on/off.  Everything else I can do from my WMC remote.  Is there anything I can do to get it off my coffee table that doesn't involve a Logitech Harmony or similar?  It seems kind of silly to buy a universal remote just to power one device on/off.

I'd prefer something a bit more elegant than duct-taping a TV-B-Gone to the bottom of my WMC remote (which is sadly the best idea I've thought of so far).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can program some of the buttons (TV power and volume) on your microsoft media center remote (Assuming that's what you have)...

1. Put the Media Center remote into
   learning mode by holding down the
   “Ok” button and the “DVD Menu”
   button at the same time. Once the
   lights have gone out, you are in
   learning mode.
2. Press the button the Media Center remote (TV Power or volume)
   that you would like to program. The
   light on the remote will flash once.
3. While holding the two remotes so that their IR nodes are facing each
   other, press the button from the
   other remote for which you would
   like the Media Center remote to
   learn. If the operation is
   successful the lights on the Media
   Center Remote will flash twice. If
   it wasn’t successful then they will
   flash four times.

[image]

Comment: I've been using this remote for many years and I did not know you could do that.  I thought one had to use the blaster things that came with it, but I never got around to using them.  Which buttons are programmable?

Comment: I don't think my one has the second power button, and it has four coloured buttons at the bottom, just like this one:  http://support.boxee.tv/attachments/token/rio0gs44ofqd8n0/?name=MCE_remote.jpg

Comment: Volume and power buttons are programmable - sorry I've never seen one without the 2nd power button on that you linked to!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that you buy a some kind of [Infrared sender](http://www.irblaster.info/) (assuming your tv-remote uses that) and use that to send the signal used by your tv-remote.

The TV-B-Gone option is way simpler in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You could always take the two remotes apart and frankenstein them together so you just have to flip the remote over to hit power. This has the same sort of issues as the TV-B-Gone though, I'd think.